# Stellar Account Viewer is Stuck on "Submitting Transaction to the Network"

Tags: transactions, wallets, ledger, ledger-nano

I submitted a transaction to send my lumens to my Nano. Stellar Account Viewer in Browser (Firefox) is stuck on "Submitting Transaction to the Network". Screen keeps attempting/animation keeps refreshing black circle with lines but nothing happens. What to do ??? Big dollars sent !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try **updating the Ledger** Nano then re-attempt.

If that doesn't work I would try doing it on the **Google Chrome browser**, **Opera browser**, or the **Brave browser**.

EDIT: As per the comments below, you can also **try clearing all history, cache, cookies from Google Chrome, as well as try restarting it**.

Comment: Thanks but same thing in Chrome.

Comment: @BobbyTrack was the firmware of the Nano updated? If that doesn't work, a few people got it work with the Brave browser so try that as well.